# Sort array recursively | multidimensional array sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, php-7.1

I need to use `sort()`, but I noticed that it does not sort multidimensional arrays.

I created this function but found out that it only works on 2 dimensional array. I need to `sort()` all nested array.

This is what it looks like now:

```
public static function sortArray($array) : array {
    sort($array);
    foreach ($array as &$index) {
        if (is_array($index)) {
            sort($index);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Is there any way to make this check and sort on all child and grandchildren?

Comment: array_multisort does not work?

Comment: `array_multisort`

Answer (score 0):

It is better you can post your array. So we have some idea. Anyways if this example solve your problem. Try this :-

```
Array
(
[item-1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => Item 1
        [order] => 3
    )

[item-2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => Item 2
        [order] => 2
    )

[item-3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [title] => Item 3
        [order] => 1
    )
)
usort($array, 'sort_by_order ');
function sort_by_order ($a, $b)
{
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
}
        Or
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'order'),SORT_ASC,$array);
```

Or may be this link will helps you :- https://blog.jachim.be/2009/09/php-msort-multidimensional-array-sort/comment-page-1/
Hope it Helps!